# Questions tagged [Minecraft] and [Minecraft-redstone]

Tags: discussion, tags, sub-tags

There are currently 113 questions tagged [minecraft-redstone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-redstone) and all but one of them are also tagged [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft). [The other](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74239/how-do-i-separate-redstone-signals-in-minecraft), is additionally tagged with [minecraft-xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-xbox).

Should every question tagged with [minecraft-redstone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-redstone) automatically be tagged with [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft)?

If yes, should [minecraft-redstone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-redstone) be removed as superfluous?

EDIT: What about removing the [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag from those questions?

The crux of my question is: should both tags be required in order to identify the question?

Answer (score 5):

The fact that two tags exclusively occur together does not make the less numerous one inherently 
superfluous.

Tags are used to represent domains of knowledge, and knowledge of general Minecraft and knowledge of redstone circuits are quite distinct. (Redstone circuits are more akin to electrical engineering than the mining or crafting that takes priority in the rest of the game).

All we are able to do is work within the confines of the existing tag system, so for the time being, tagging both [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) and [minecraft-redstone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-redstone) are the best we can do.